# How to clear table contents in notes for iOS 11?

Tags: ios, notes.app

I don’t want to create a new table I want to empty the data of the old table and add new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the cells you wish to clear by dragging the orange circular handles on the corners of the selected cell region, then choose Cut from the popup menu.